# for loop batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command

How can I copy the batch file to subdirectories, run it, then delete the batch file?

I am working on a batch file that will automatically change the folder icon of the folder it is in. Shown below:

```
@ECHO OFF

attrib +s "%CD%"
set ICODIR=%CD%\Icon\

for %%F in ("%ICODIR%"*.ico) do set ICO=%%~nxF

set ICOINI=Desktop.ini

IF EXIST Desktop.ini (
    attrib -s -h %ICOINI%
)

echo [.ShellClassInfo] > %ICOINI%
echo IconResource=%ICODIR:~2%%ICO%>>%ICOINI%
echo InfoTip=%ICO:~0,-4%>>%ICOINI%

attrib -a +s +h %ICOINI%

Pause
```

This works, after many problems found out that it will not create the folder icon until a file is deleted within that directory.

I have been trying to work on a for loop that will list all sub directories and store their names. Though it lists the root directory first. How can I get it to skip the root directory? Code shown Below:

```
@ECHO OFF

for /R /D "delims=\" %%d IN (%CD%) do echo %%~nd

Pause
```

EDIT: Why is the file only made in the last folder?

```
for /D /R "%cd%" %%d IN (*) do (

    set something=%%~nd 
    echo TEST>%something%\Desktop.txt
)
```

Comment: Your first script works for me (Win7). What has to be deleted before it works?

Comment: @Jubjub Bandersnatch When I run it, it does exactly what it is supposed to do except actually change the folder icon (Also Win7), it will only chance the icon when a file is deleted within the folder.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with Explorer rather than your script, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for /D /R "%cd%" %%d IN (*) do echo %%~d
```

`%cd%` wouldn't be listed.

Comment: Works well! Changed end variable to %%~nd to just get the folder name, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Interesting scenario.

Try looking into the `forfiles` command at http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html .
However using the `for` command this is the best solution I could come up with.

```
:loop
set /a count+=1

for /f "tokens=%count% delims=\" %%a in ("%CD%") do (echo %%a > 
output.txt)

if %count% == 8 exit
goto :loop
```

Note this is not the best answer but it works. This instance will check a maximum of 7 directories in from the drive letter but by incrementing the `if` check.

This Worked for me, hope it helps.

Yours Mona.

Comment: Thanks, it looks as though it would do the trick, although the sub directories contain around 1,000-2,000 folders. I will have to up the loop and test it!

Comment: wow, u should REALLY try `forfiles` its very useful sometimes over the `for /r` command

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, I found that adding an IF statement allows you to filter out the root of the search. Your example didn't work at all for me, so I had to modify it a little. /R prepends the current dir in the search (not %CD%) to the loop variable, so I had to strip some sentinel value out. I deemed it unlikely enough to find files with "ZZZZZ" in the name, but your filesystem may need a different sentinel.

```
FOR /R "%CD%" %%d IN (ZZZZZ) do @(SET "D=%%~d" & SET "D=!D:\ZZZZZ=!" & IF NOT "!D!"=="%CD%" @ECHO !D!)
```